# Django: Create two models with a CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a CreateView for creating a customer, but I also need to create an 'identification' model along with this customer. I have an identification model that has a foreign key to the model because we need to be able to add any amount of IDs to some (Drivers license, Passport, etc)

Anyways, the current code (Which only creates a new customer) looks like this:

```
class CustomerCreationView(CreateView):
    template_name = "customers/customer_information.html"
    form_class = CustomerInformationForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(CustomerCreationView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context_data.update({
            'new_customer': True,
        })

        return context_data
```

CustomerInformationForm is ModelForm. I would like to create another ModelForm for Identifications, but I do not know how to add the second form to a CreateView. I found [this article](http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/), but it is 5 years old and not talking about a CreateView.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `CreateWithInlinesView` from [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views). The code would look like this:

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSet


class IdentificationInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Identification


class CustomerCreationView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = CustomerInformation
    inlines = [IdentificationInline]
```

Comment: I generally don't like to turn to 3rd parties for "small" things like this, but I took a look at this and several other things django-extra-views offers, and it seems like a very nice package. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomerCreationView(CreateView):
    template_name = "customers/customer_information.html"
    form_class = CustomerInformationForm
    other_form_class = YourOtherForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(CustomerCreationView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context_data.update({
            'new_customer': True,
            'other_form': other_form_class,    
        })

        return context_data
```

Comment: But, when you do a POST, it only create the CustomerInformationForm, not the another.

Comment: You have to add a custom "def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):" that takes your form and save the data