# CreateView() with two models

Tags: python, django, forms, model, django-class-based-views

In my project I offer the possibility to create tags (called genres) for a different model in the project. To do so I use a very simple [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView).

```
class GenreCreate(CreateView):
    model = Genre
    form_class = GenreForm
```

I just realized that it would be possible that users create new genres that would basically be just different names for already existing genres (for example a new genre called "hiphop" when a genre "rap" already exists).

For this reason I created a new model "GenreCopy". My `models.py` looks like this

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('stations:list')


class GenreCopy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    linksTo = models.ForeignKey(Genre)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('stations:list')
```

---

**[Insert]**
*Question:* Why did I create a new model `GenreCopy` instead of adding some fields to `Genre`?
*Answer:* A regular genre should have a name, a description and a color but (of course) no link to another genre. A copied genre, on the other hand, should only have a name and a link to another genre, but no description and no color. Saving genres and copied genres to the same table would (in my opinion) violate [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

---

Now I want to create a form where I can either create a new genre or choose an already existing genre to link. In the first case, model `Genre` should be used, in the second case I want to use `GenreCopy`.

What's the best way to achieve this with CBVs?

What I found so far is [Django: Create two models with a CreateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179266/django-create-two-models-with-a-createview), but as this question is already more than one year old and I don't like to use 3rd party apps that much I wanted to know if there are better ways.

Comment: Instead of creating `GenCopy` you can have a `ForeignKey` relationship with `self`.

Comment: @Rohan I thought about that, but in case a genre is a copy, I would not want it to have a description and a color. Otherwise, if it's not a copy, it should not have a link to another genre. Therefore it feels to me like I should use two models. Maybe you are still right that this solution would at least be easier.

Comment: I would make a genre_name -> genre mapping. You'd have a table for genres that do not contain names and another that tells what genre a name means.

Comment: @Joonazan sounds good - what's that? :)

Comment: table1: (id | description | color)
table2: (name | id)
Seems like i can't put newlines in comments. :(