# Any Class Based Views or Package for Auth with related model?

Tags: python, django

Currently I have two styles of templates: User + Client, and User + Company. And I want to create a view to create a User + account from either of these two related templates.

Currently I have achieved this, but there is a problem: the code seems to be very bloated, and I also do not know if there is CBV to edit model with related models, then it will result in other views also bloated.

Is there any way to improve this?

models.py: https://pastebin.com/9Fp0F6CG

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.views import generic
from .forms import UserForm, ClientForm, CompanyForm

class ClientFormView(generic.View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template_name = "users/registration/form_client.html"
        context = {"form_user": UserForm, "form_client": ClientForm}
        return render(request, template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template_name = "users/registration/form_client.html"
        context = {"form_user": UserForm, "form_client": ClientForm}

        form_user = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_client = ClientForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid() and form_client.is_valid():
            # get data for auth and login
            email = form_user.cleaned_data["email"]
            password_raw = form_user.cleaned_data["password1"]

            # add user_type = client
            instance_user = form_user.save(commit=False)
            instance_user.user_type = "cl"
            instance_user.save()

            instance_client = form_client.save(commit=False)

            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password_raw)
            if user is not None:
                # add the user in related user field
                instance_client.user = user
                instance_client.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("main:home")

        return render(request, template_name, context)


class CompanyFormView(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template_name = "users/registration/form_company.html"
        context = {"form_user": UserForm, "form_company": CompanyForm}
        return render(request, template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template_name = "users/registration/form_company.html"
        context = {"form_user": UserForm, "form_company": CompanyForm}

        form_user = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_company = CompanyForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid() and form_company.is_valid():
            # get data for auth and login
            email = form_user.cleaned_data["email"]
            password_raw = form_user.cleaned_data["password1"]

            # add user_type = client
            instance_user = form_user.save(commit=False)
            instance_user.user_type = "comp"
            instance_user.save()

            instance_company = form_company.save(commit=False)

            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password_raw)
            if user is not None:
                # add the user in related user field
                instance_company.user = user
                instance_company.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("main:home")

        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only made some improvements in regards to the views, I haven't looked at the models.

- First you should change from the generic `generic.View` to
  `generic.CreateView` since you are creating stuff.
- When deriving from `generic.CreateView` you can move out the
  `template_name` and `context` from the functions and put them in the
  class instead, since they stay the same for both the **GET** and
  **POST** operations.
- Then you don't need to user the `render` functions, you can just call
  the `super` that should handle the render for you.
- And lastly you can create a mixin that handles the logic in the user
  creation, as it's largely the same.

With the suggestions above it should look something like this. You might need to tweak it, I haven't been able to test it fully.

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSet

class ClientCompanyMixin(object):

    def create_user(self, form_user, form_second, type):
        # get data for auth and login
        email = form_user.cleaned_data["email"]
        password_raw = form_user.cleaned_data["password1"]

        # add user_type = client/company
        instance_user = form_user.save(commit=False)
        instance_user.user_type = type
        instance_user.save()

        instance = form_second.save(commit=False)

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password_raw)

        return instance, user

class UserInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = User

class ClientFormView(CreateWithInlinesView, ClientCompanyMixin):
    template_name = "users/registration/form_client.html"
    model = Client
    inlines = [UserInline]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form_user"] = UserForm
        context["form_client"] = ClientForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form_user = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_client = ClientForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid() and form_client.is_valid():

            instance_client, user = self.create_user(form_user, form_client, "cl")

            if user is not None:
                # add the user in related user field
                instance_client.user = user
                instance_client.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("main:home")

        return super(ClientFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

class CompanyFormView(CreateWithInlinesView, ClientCompanyMixin):
    template_name = "users/registration/form_company.html"
    model = Company
    inlines = [UserInline]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CompanyFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form_user"] = UserForm
        context["form_company"] = CompanyForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_user = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_company = CompanyForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid() and form_company.is_valid():

            instance_company, user = self.create_user(form_user, form_company, "comp")

            if user is not None:
                # add the user in related user field
                instance_company.user = user
                instance_company.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("main:home")

        return super(CompanyFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It improved the code a bit, thx. My question is more because I do not know Django's forms very well and do not know if there are packages for it.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, packages for what?

Comment: Packages with extra views. I've seen some, mostly older ones, that implement views based on classes that are now part of django.

Comment: Yes, I've used one of them (and applied its improvements) in my answer, more specifically the `generic.CreateView`. You can read more of them at [Built-in class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: This view raises an error, because there is no "model = some_model"

Comment: Yeah, the view is complaining that no model is defined. You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173510/10400050) in how to use multiple models in a `CreateView`. I've updated my answer to include that part.